# Trying to take input from android microphone and send it to pc

Tags: java, android

Everything works fine until I try to put what I receive on pc into a `wav` file.

I think its a problem in the saving to wav file part. Tried almost everything, `AudioSystem.write` etc,nothing seems to work.

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.This is the code:

```
class Server {

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    static AudioInputStream ais;
    static AudioFormat format;
    static boolean status = true;
    static int port = 50005;
    static int sampleRate = 48000;

    static DataLine.Info dataLineInfo;
    static SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/output.wav"));
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        int i = 0;
        /**
         * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
         * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
         * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
         * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
         */

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];

        format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
        dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        sourceDataLine.open(format);
        sourceDataLine.start();

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(1.00f);

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);
        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());
        while (status == true&&i<100) {
            i++;
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());

            try {
                outstream.write(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getData().length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        sourceDataLine.stop(); //after i has reacher 100 this happens
        sourceDataLine.close();
        outstream.close();

    }
}
```